# Export Animatet Character to Threejs json has invisible material

Tags: export, three.js

Hy I try to do some examples in threejs and would like to use Blender for modeling and animating.

I startet using an existing obj File i found some where in the internet and added an armature and everithing.

So far the animating and everything works fine, except my exports have some how invalid Materials. (Three js won't show anything except i change the material to a custom Material by Code with in threejs)

Here i have made a Screen Capture on what i have done:
http://lukas.achatz.ws/tst/export%20character.gif

The export files can be found here: http://lukas.achatz.ws/tst/MewTwo.zip

**Does some one know what i am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TGA textures require some particular [workarounds for use in three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4735) (or [on the web in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083684/how-can-i-show-a-tga-image-in-a-img-tga)). The easiest fix is probably just to convert your images to PNG or JPG.

EDIT: another problem is that the opacity must not be 0.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I retried it. I converted the TGA to a PNG with gimp and updated the json file. Still the same problem. Currently i am a littlebit busy. But I think I can upload a demo on the Weekend.

Comment: Hm ok. In addition to a demo, if you can post the source `.blend` file that might be helpful also. :)

Comment: Sry i was a little bit bussy i found the error first of all yeah .png is working :) the other problem was that the opacity of the material was equal 0 :3